# Best encryption/decryption with salt in PHP 7

Tags: php, encryption

I am looking for the simplest and secured way to encrypt/decrypt a string with a specific salt in PHP7

```
my string + specific salt = encryped data 
decode(encryped data) = my string
```

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15884537/3084005), but mcrypt_encrypt seems to be deprecated. Do you have any other suggestion or example ? Thank you

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/how-do-you-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OpenSSL functions are a good way to go. Official docs here:

- http://php.net/manual/es/function.openssl-encrypt.php
- http://php.net/manual/es/function.openssl-decrypt.php

Hope it helps!

Comment: English: https://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php https://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php